# Is it possible to call functions within a case statement?

Tags: sql, function, case

Is it possible to call functions within a `case` statement?

Example:

```
(CASE WHEN (((POWER((1+x1/x2),Term) - 1) > 0) THEN 
    10 ELSE dbo.fnx(x1,x2,x3) END) as [123]
```

Comment: Simple way to find out: Try it, if you get errors =>>> you can't. It is even quicker then ask a question is SO.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: just looked back at this question after three years. Seems like so long ago for me. Thanks for the responses. Now I can't live without SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tough you could just try it...

CASE input_expression

`input_expression`
Is the expression evaluated when the simple CASE format is used. input_expression is any valid expression.

What is a valid expression?:

> An expression can be any of the following:

- Constant
- **Function**  <====
- Column name
- Variable
- Subquery
- CASE, NULLIF, or COALESCE

**resources:**

[case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181765%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190718%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: (Note that stored-procedures are *not* on that list...) Anyway, have a link to the MSDN source?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, you are missing a bracket:

```
(CASE WHEN (((POWER((1+x1/x2),Term) - 1) > 0)) THEN   
10 ELSE dbo.fnx(x1,x2,x3) END) as [123]
```

If that doesn't fix your problem, you can investigate the user's permissions

EDIT:

On second thought you are having too many brackets, this is much more readable:

```
CASE WHEN POWER(1+x1/x2,Term) - 1 > 0 THEN   
10 ELSE dbo.fnx(x1,x2,x3) END as [123]
```